# Keep row in Table 1 if all values exist in Table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble constructing this sql query.

I have one table with Canadian and American cities like this:

```
+-------------+------------------+
|start        |finish            |
+-------------+------------------+
|      Calgary|         Vancouver|
|     Edmonton|           Toronto|
|     Montreal|          New York|
|      Chicago|          St Louis|
|        Miami|          Winnipeg|
+-------------+------------------+
```

And I have another table with only Canadian cities

```
+-------------+
|cities       |
+-------------+
|      Calgary|
|     Edmonton|
|     Montreal|
|    Vancouver|
|      Toronto|
|     Winnipeg|
+-------------+
```

And I would like to filter the first table to only keep rows where BOTH `start` and `finish` exist in the `cities` table, like so:

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
+-------------+------------------+
|start        |finish            |
+-------------+------------------+
|      Calgary|         Vancouver|
|     Edmonton|           Toronto|
+-------------+------------------+
```

My initial thought was this:

```
SELECT *
FROM start_finish s, cities c
WHERE c.cities = s.start and c.cities = s.finish
```

But I realize after some trial and error that that would only return values if start and finish are the same.

```
+-------------+------------------+
|start        |finish            |
+-------------+------------------+
|      Calgary|           Calgary|
+-------------+------------------+
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are joining with c.cities = s.finish so obviously it should return rows where they are same :) please add sample data of your expected output. This will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` or `exists`:

```
select sf.*
from start_finish sf
where exists (select 1 from cities c where c.city = sf.start
             ) and
      exists (select 1 from cities c where c.city = sf.finish
             ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner join twice. Once for the `start`, once for the `finish`.

```
SELECT sf1.start,
       sf1.finish
       FROM start_finish sf1
            INNER JOIN cities c1
                       ON c1.cities = sf1.start
            INNER JOIN cities c2
                       ON c2.cities = sf1.finish;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fe0ac372b4a6facdacb1424b2827a0fc)